# jQuery: Changing Top Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to change the top value of an element(.zoomWindow) that has inline styles. The inline styles come from a JS plugin I'm using to zoom images. The parent of the element has position:relative, and the element itself has position absolute. Below is my code, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var blockHeight = $('#product-gallery .zoomPad:first-child > img').height();
  $('.jqzoom:nth-child(3) .zoomWindow').css('top', blockHeight);   
});
```

Comment: CSS processors in most modern browsers don't accept integers as units. Try affixing the `px` unit to the integer that `.height()` returns.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
   var blockHeight = $('#product-gallery .zoomPad:first-child > img').height();
   $('.jqzoom:nth-child(3) .zoomWindow').css('top', blockHeight);   
};
```

Comment: I had to change "windows" to "window", but it worked :)

Comment: I hope you did not actually use window.onload when you have jQuery.

Comment: @epascarello Why not?

Comment: Use jQuery to bind an `onLoad` event listener rather than overwriting the entire `onLoad` function for the `window`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a debug statement of `console.log(blockHeight);` will show a value of zero for the image height.

`document.ready` fires before images are fully loaded. So the image will have a height of zero. You should do this check with window onload or image load.

Comment: Code with bad practice and with no explanation of the problem. How hard is it to do `window.on("load", function() { /* your code */ } );`

Comment: I didn't actually know how to use window.onload. If you write the code for me I'll accept your answer.